# make my idea possible , give a name for canvas input file image

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

```
function handleImage(e)
{
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(event)
    {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function()
        {
           var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img);
           imgInstance.setWidth(50);
           imgInstance.setHeight(50);
           imgInstance.set({maxWidth:120,maxHeight:100});
           imgInstance.setLeft(50);
           imgInstance.top  = 50;
           canvas.add(imgInstance);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

my intention is when i add image to canvas using input file , at the same time it also add the image to a div.

now if the user delete the canvas image the div image also be deleted , but how i going to make this possible? i need some on image canvas detail.

my question
1.can anyone point me a right way to doing it ? making this idea possible
2.can i give the canvas image a name ?

something like imgInstance.name("mymainimage");

check my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/ckqk2Lzs/18/) if you are not understand ,it will make more clearly.

1.try add few small image.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about fabricjs but you can certainly keep a reference to an instance of your canvas image in dictionary/map (js object) and retrieve it by key (your unique name).

```
canvasImgByKey = {};
// Keep reference before adding to canvas.
canvasImgByKey[imgNameHere] = imgInstance;
...
// Get by reference later on.
imgInstance = canvasImgByKey[imgNameHere];

// ... do something with the instance here (delete) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to react to something like the delete key pressed, add an event listener:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_id");
canvas.addEventListener( "keydown", keyDown, true);

function keyDown(e) {
    // check keyCode, delete is 46
    if ( e.keyCode == 46 ) {
        // remove here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ckqk2Lzs/20/

jQuery

```
function onKeyDownHandler(e)
{
    switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 46: // delete
          //delete item
          var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
          if (activeObject) 
          {
            canvas.remove(activeObject);
            $('img').filter("[src='"+activeObject.getSrc()+"']").hide();
          }
          return;
    }
}
```

Just look for the `img` element which has the activeObject's source and then simply hide it.

P.S. this won't work for multiple images that are the same but I hope this points you in the right direction